# Query string in url too long

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, url

I have a multi-select used as a filter. I'm creating an array of int to pass all the selected items to the controller, via ajax.

```
var selectedItems = [];
$.each($("#myDropDown option:selected"), function () {
    selectedItems.push($(this).val());
});
```

It could have many items (more than 500) in this multi-select. For exemple, if the user selects 499 items, the resulting query string is too long for the IIS server.

I know I can change the `maxQueryString` in the config file. Maybe I'm wrong but it doesn't seems to be a good idea.

Today I will set it for exemple to 30000, tomorrow the multi-select contains 1000 items and what, I will change to 60000 ?

Is there any other way to pass selected items ? (I don't know, variable or whatever).

Thanks

EDIT:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Defaults/GetFilteredDefaults',
    data: {
        vehiculesFilter: selectedVehicules,
        sectorsFilter: selectedSectors,
        imputationsFilter:selectedImputations,
        missionsFilter:selectedMissions,
        piecesFilter:selectedPieces,               
        localizationsFilter:selectedLocalizations
    },
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
        createDefaultList(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Use a POST request instead?

Comment: As mentioned don't use the GET method, use the POST method and add your data to the body of the request.

Comment: Avoid passing long array as query string (since you need to convert it as JSON string). Use POST in your AJAX request instead.

Comment: I've just edited my post. I don't really understand what to do to be a POST method.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can create a form and data post with `JSON.stringify($('#yourformid').serializeObject())` in AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Defaults/GetFilteredDefaults',
    data: JSON.stringify($('#yourformid').serializeObject()),
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
        createDefaultList(result);
    }
});
```

But you should add the function in your script:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok just add `type:post` in ajax and change the controller method to `[HttpPost]`.
Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code is absolutely fine and there is nothing much you can do about it with code at the front end as the limit is set at the server to accept URL parameters as string.

How do we make it work?
Change your server methods to accept the data in a predefined model, may be a class with properties. Here is the class you should have at your back end if it is C# Web API:

```
   public class QueryModel
    {
        public string vehiculesFilter { get; set; }
        public string sectorsFilter { get; set; }
        public string imputationsFilter { get; set; }
        public string missionsFilter { get; set; }
        public string piecesFilter { get; set; }
        public string localizationsFilter { get; set; }
    }
```

And your controller method should be:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetFilteredDefaults(QueryModel filtersObject){
//     Your code logic to build response comes here
       return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```